# How to stop a rectangle from moving off of the canvas in Javascript using the p5 library

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my Javascript:

```
var x;
var y;
var ymod = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  x = 10;
  y = 12;
}

function draw() {
  background(48, 48, 48);
  noStroke();
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  rect(x, y, 10, 30);
  y = y + ymod;
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
  ymod = -1;
  } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
  ymod = 1;
  }
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Game</title>
    <script src="libraries/p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.dom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like the rectangle to stop when it hits the edges of the canvas (ie: y=0 and y=570). I have tried to add

```
if (y=0) {
ymod = 0;
}
```

to the end of the draw function but, it breaks everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the [`constrain`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/constrain) function in p5.js, to constrain `y` between 0 and 570, like this:

```
y = constrain(y, 0, 570);
```

The reason why `if (y = 0)` breaks everything is because a single equals sign sets `y` to 0 instead of comparing. To test if y = 0, you'll need to use a triple equals sign instead (`y === 0`).